# Using logistic regression to model cumulative probability of a ordinal response

Tags: logistic, mixed-model, generalized-linear-model

I have observations of students test results (response variable) as the ordinal variable test *score* (grade A < grade B < grade C < grade D). Students belongs to several different *school*s. The predictor is *education_type*. However, I could not get the test score of each individual student, but only the cumulative distribution of the score among students per school i: Prob{grade=A|school=i}, Prob{grade<=B|school=i}, Prob{grade<=C|school=i}. So the probabilities have the following property:

0 <= Prob{grade=A|school=i} <= Prob{grade<=B|school=i} <= Prob{grade<=C|school=i} <=1

I was suggested to do the following analysis.

For every sampled school, we end up with 3 estimated cumulative probabilities. Using the cumulative probabilities as response, we apply a logistic regression with *grade* and *education_type* as predictor.

Could someone help me to clarify whether the above method is valid? Would the 3 cumulative probabilities be non-independent? and how can I disentangle/model such dependency, by introducing school as a random factor?

Comment: You could not fit a model with student-level covariates, but if all your covariates is at school-level, you are just fine!

Comment: @kjetil b halvorsen. Thanks. Do I need to incorporate the dependencies between the three observed probabilities per school?

Comment: You need not only the proportions per school, but the actual counts! Those three counts is then a vector response, they are of course not independent, but the ordinal logistic regression take care of that.

Comment: However, I dont have the actual score per student, so a ordinal logistic regression is not possible in my case. I only have the cumulative distribution per school.